# Am using Laravel 5.4: and js not loading in blade during editing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5.4

Below is the way i've referenced my js scripts only happens in CRUD when updating data but not when creating new data.

```
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/chosen.jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/spinbox.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/moment.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/daterangepicker.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/jquery.knob.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/autosize.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/jquery.inputlimiter.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js/bootstrap-tag.min.js')}}"></script>
public function getEdit($id)
    {
        $data = ::find($id);

        return view('editData', compact('data'));
    }
```

Routing code:

```
 Route::get('/editData/{id}','dataController@getEdit');
```

Kindly assist.

Comment: Use {{ asset('PATH TO ASSET') }} instead of URL::to.

Comment: where is the class from  `::find($id);` ??

Comment: what do you mean by this `js scripts only happens in CRUD when updating data but not when creating new data.`?

Comment: @Niek van der Maaden i tried it but never worked

Comment: @madalin ivascu - from the controller

Comment: @Chonchol  - when inserting data i don't experience it but happens when editing, after routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i worked it out i loaded all js scripts references after the HTML code at the footer and it worked. Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

I think your asset urls get broken  somewhere along the request. Try to use `<script src="{!! asset('js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js') !!}"></script>`. You should inspect your browser to find out if the files are being loaded. You could find valuable insight to your problem.